# SQL query inner joins and limit to max 3 most recent

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `product` INNER JOIN `shop`
ON `product`.shop_id= `shop`.id;
```

I wanted to get all of the products from all the shops I have, but I wanted to get 3 products max from each shop. Is there a way to specify MAX on each joins?

Here's my product table:

[image]

Here's my shop table:

[image]

Comment: Use a subquery for the products and use the mainquery for shop. That way you don't have join and can use LIMIT for 3 results on your products

Comment: Add table structure and some sample data with output which you want

Comment: Can you post desired output? What do you mean by get max 3 products?

Comment: show all columns from products table, which 3? random products?

Comment: @AshReva I mean for every store I only want to get the 3 most recent products.

Comment: recent is by `updated` column ?

Comment: @cant see anything in the image of shops table

Comment: @AshReva if you zoom in, you can see it

Comment: There are no records in shops table and also just 1 row in product table

Comment: May be this link would help:
http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * 
      FROM (SELECT *, IF(@shop = (@shop:=p.shop_id), @id:=@id + 1, @id := 1) temp 
            FROM `product` p, (SELECT @shop:=0, @id:=1) AS A 
            ORDER BY p.shop_id, p.updated DESC) AS B 
      WHERE temp <= 3) AS C
INNER JOIN `shop` s ON C.shop_id= s.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `product` p
INNER JOIN `shop` s
  ON `p`.shop_id= `s`.id
WHERE  p.id IN (SELECT p2.id
                 FROM `product` p2
                 WHERE p2.shop_id = s.id
                 ORDER BY p2.updated DESC
                 LIMIT 3)
```

OR maybe:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `product` p
INNER JOIN `shop` s
  ON `p`.shop_id= `s`.id
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT p2.id
              FROM `product` p2
              WHERE p2.shop_id = s.id
              ORDER BY p2.updated DESC
              LIMIT 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Specifying limits within a subquery is a bit challenging in MySQL (not impossible, but a bit complicated).

If you just want the three most recent product ids for each shop, and you can live with them on one row, then you can use `group_concat()`.  The query is much simpler:

```
SELECT shop.*,
       substring_index(group_concat(product.id order by product.updated desc), ',', 3) as ThreeProducts
FROM `product` INNER JOIN
     `shop`
     ON `product`.shop_id= `shop`.id
group by shop.id;
```

The results will place the product ids in a single field like this:  `'1,2,3'`.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to know the tables definitions in terms of primary keys, foreign keys, etc to come up with a SQL to solve the problem. From the images it is not clear if product.id is unique or not. I suspect there is possibly a data model definition issue here.
If the tables are not normalized to a necessary extent, it will be very difficult (sometime not possible) to read appropriate data back. 
A reasonably normalized tables should look like.

Product(id primary key, ....)

Shop(id primary key,....)

and a relation table say.

Shop_Product (shop_id references Shop(id), prod_id references Product(id), ...)

It will be helpful to help you out if you could send table definitions.

Answer (score 0):

try to use limit in your code. It may work